# Please help me form appropriate SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

This must be trivial I know, but I've been tryin for so long to get it working.
Here's snapshot of my table:
[image]

And here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT _id, table_number 
FROM ordersTable 
GROUP BY table_number 
ORDER BY table_number
```

And here's the snapshot of the result of this query:

[image]

And what I want is instead of id = 10 in result, i want is id = 8, i.e., i want the record with the minimum id, grouped by table numbers.

Comment: What happens when you order by `id` as well?

Comment: @Shomz: only the order of the rows in result changes (i used this: SELECT _id, table_number FROM ordersTable GROUP BY table_number ORDER BY table_number DESC)

Comment: Try this: `SELECT _id, table_number FROM ordersTable GROUP BY table_number ORDER BY table_number, id DESC`

Comment: @Shomz : shows same result as in question...nywayz, answer by "juergen d" worked...thnx 4 ur help :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT min(_id), table_number
FROM ordersTable 
GROUP BY table_number 
ORDER BY table_number
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [min](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function.

```
SELECT MIN(_id), 
       table_number 
FROM   orderstable 
GROUP  BY table_number 
ORDER  BY table_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.

If you want to order your resultset by id then change your Order By clause:
`SELECT id, table_number FROM ordersTable GROUP BY table_number ORDER BY id`

If you want the minimum id:
`SELECT min(id), table_number FROM ordersTable GROUP BY table_number`